# SQL subqueries ques :

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have these 3 tables :

1)`Sailors (sid:INT, sname:VARCHAR(30), rating:INT, age:INT)`

2)`Boats (bid:INT, bname:VARCHAR(30), color:VARCHAR(10))`

3)`Reserves (bid:INT, sid:INT, day:DATE)`

I don't know how to build a query that displays : 
The names of the sailors who have reserved at least 2 boats in different colors!

Comment: Try.  Then edit your question with the attempt.

Comment: include your sample data and expected output, with tried attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group for each sailor, and then demand that there are at least 2 distinct colors in that group:

```
select  s.sid
,       s.sname
,       count(distinct b.color) as NumberOfBoatColorsReserved
from    Reserves r
join    Sailors s
on      s.sid = r.sid
join    Boats b
on      b.bid = r.bid
group by
        s.sid
,       s.sname
having  count(distinct b.color) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but here is a quick and dry solution:

```
SELECT sname FROM Sailors 
JOIN Reserves USING (sid) 
JOIN Boats USING (bid) 
GROUP BY sname, color 
HAVING COUNT(sname) >= 2;
```

Added Selecting Unique BID:

```
SELECT bid FROM Sailors 
JOIN Reserves USING (sid) 
JOIN Boats USING (bid)
HAVING COUNT(bid) >= 3;
```

Where 3 represents the total number of sailors that are in the database. This can be queried separately and quite simply using COUNT